# Fabric write Log to android logcat in addition to Fabric dashboard in Android

Tags: android, logcat, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I am using Fabric crashlytics for crash reporting. Fabric write log to android logcat in addition to fabric dashboard. I want to disable android logcat messages, but found no such method.

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `Crashlytics.log(msg);` **not** `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logging)

"The recommended way to add custom logging to your app is `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);`. In addition to writing to the next crash report, it will also write to the LogCat using `android.util.Log.println(priority, tag, msg`). If you don’t want to write to LogCat you should call: `Crashlytics.log(msg);` which will only write to the Crashlytics crash report."